# Presenting output of while loop as selection for user

Tags: python-3.x

Here is what I have so far

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import netifaces
interfaces = [i for i in netifaces.interfaces() if not i.startswith(("lo", "ipsec", "tun"))]
count = len(interfaces)
i = 0
x = 0
  while i < len(interfaces):  
  print("Interface " + interfaces[i])  
  i += 1  
  x += 1
```

This will print a list of interfaces but I would like to present that list as something the customer can select.
i.e. "Please select external interface 1.) enp1s0 2.) enp0s21f0u4 3.) wlp2s0 4.) exit

Thank you for any help you can provide

Comment: you can use `user_input = input("Please select external interface:")`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Python relies upon indentation to block out the code, so the indentation on that `while` statement is a problem.  You generally don't need as many counter variables as you may have to use in C.  I don't know if you're using `count` and `x` later on in your code, but you're not using them here so I took them out.  Without the counters you can take out that `while` and replace it with a `for`.

This has no input-validation, but try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import netifaces

interfaces = [i for i in netifaces.interfaces() if not i.startswith(("lo", "ipsec", "tun"))]

print("Choose an interface:")
for i in range(len(interfaces)):
    print("\t{}) ".format(i+1), interfaces[i])

sel = int(input("\n> "))-1

print("You have selected interface {}.".format(interfaces[sel]))
```

You mentioned that you're doing this for a customer:  make sure you validate that input before converting it to an `int()` and using it.

Answer (score -1):

Just add this lines:

```
print("Please select external interface:\n 1.) enp1s0\n 2.) enp0s21f0u4\n 3.) wlp2s0\n 4.) exit\n")
value = input("")
```